# Gmail not sending email via Expo-mail-composer when attachments are presents

Tags: android, expo, gmail

On a expo app, I'm using expo-mail-composer

When trying to send an email with attachments on emulator via Gmail, it runs smoothly and I receive the email.

when trying to do the same on a actual phone, the email is send to drafts without attachments.

sending an email without attachments works fine.

for record, I'm testing with the Expo Go app

here is a snippet of the code I use:

```js
    const sendDebugEmail = (inMemoryDatas: InMemoryData[], dataInBody = false) => {
        createFilesFromString(inMemoryDatas) // creates a list of files and returns Uris
            .then(async (attachmentsUris: string[]) => {
                    await MailComposer.composeAsync({
                        recipients: ["anEmail@domain.com"],
                        subject: "Data",
                        attachments: attachmentsUris,
                        body: "mail body"),
                    });
                }
            )
    }
```

I tried to build an APK and run it on the phone, with the same consequences.

With another Email application (selected when the intent is sent to Android) or on the emulator even with Gmail, it works fine.

Comment: We cannot see what kind of uris you use.

Comment: @blackapps it's an array of simple string (for instance `["debug/myfile.json"]`

Comment: I see no kind. That is no uri. Tell the values. The whole uri string. Give examples.

Comment: @blackapps sorry for the delay,

Here is some uri string actually used:

This is the one used on the emulator
`file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/debug/debug-store-effectifs-2024-02-09T09:15:36.411Z.json`  

And one on the actual phone: 
`file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/debug/debug-store-effectifs-2024-02-09T09:17:20.355Z.json`  

I see no difference so I suspect the problem is from Gmail...

Comment: Normally when you share a file with another app you cannot use a file uri. As the other app will mostly not have access to your file path. And in your case its an app specific/private path. So no chance. Normally you would use FileProvider now to give you a nice content scheme uri. File uris cannot be used anymore.

Comment: @blackapps thanks a lot, I will give it a try. That could explains why it's working on my emulator (which is quite old) and not on my phone which is up to date :)